# Как работает данная строчка

Tags: python, list

Объясните пожалуйста как работает данная строчка. Я понимаю что она из списка, где значения кортежи, делает просто список со значениям, но как она работает, зачем там метод sum. Спасибо)

```
var = [(data,),(data2,),(data3,)...]
new = list(sum(var, ()))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) возвращает сумму элементов переданного объекта и имеет следующее определение:

> **sum**(*iterable*, */*, *start=0*)

Первым параметром она принимает итерируемый объект (например кортеж или список), а вторым — начальное значение — значение, к которому будут прибавляться элементы итерируемого объекта.

Приведённый Вами код аналогичен следующему:

```py
start = ()
for t in var:
    start += t

new = list(start)
```

---

[`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) — это конструктор списка. В него можно передать итерируемую последовательность, которая будет конвертирована в список.

Сначала может показаться, что `list` — это функция, так как классы в Python принято именовать в стиле `CamelCase`. Но это именно класс, а его имя оставлено в таком виде по некоторым историческим соображениям.